# Swipe images in phoneap + jquery issue

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am building a phonegap app  using javacsript and jquery.I wrote this piece of code to swipe images.

```
$('#fullscreen').swipeleft(function () {
        //Show next image
        showNext();
        alert('Left');
 });

function showNext() {
$("#fullscreen").attr('src', "images/next.png");
}
```

But when I swipe, the image doesn't change and I get the error "09-13 14:49:21.188: W/webview(20238): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down."

After browsing through some forums I added the following code.

```
var fullScr = document.getElementById("fullscreen");
    fullScr.addEventListener( "touchstart", function(e){ onStart(e); }, false );
    function onStart ( touchEvent ) {
      if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ) {
        touchEvent.preventDefault();
      }
}
```

But it still doesn't work.Although when I change my screen orientation from portrait to landscape, the image changes. 
What is it that happens when I change the orientation and how could I get it working in the same orientation (portrait/landscape) please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried your code without alert("Left")?

Comment: Yes I have tried without the alert. It doesn't work!!

Answer (score 0):

Well it worked for me :S... I used version 1.5.0 of Cordova and run the app on Android simulator 4.0.3. Could you try the following example?

HTML content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

        <!--  BASIC INCLUDES - TO BE MODIFIED ACCORDING TO YOUR CONVENIENCE -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.structure-1.1.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

        <!--  END - BASIC INCLUDES -->

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        $(function() {
            $('#fullscreen').swipeleft(function () {
                //Show next image
                showNext();
            });

            function showNext() {
                $("#fullscreen").attr('src', "./images/next.png");
            }
        });

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="content">
                <img id="fullscreen" src="./images/previous.png"></img>
            </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**NB: Make sure of the following things:**

- Modify the source of the "basic includes" of the code to your convenience (source of the CSS / JS files of jQuery / jQuery Mobile)
- Change the source of the version of cordova if yours is not 1.5.0

---

Hope this will work for you too. Anyway, let me know about your result.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Its now working for me with the same code I had but with a minor change in the way i am invoking it.The change is: ~$('#fullscreen').swipeleft(showNext);~ I am using Cordova 1.8.1 and running it on my device which has Android 2.2.1